# Can we develop a functional or process bot using azure service

Tags: botframework, bots, chatbot, azure-bot-service

I'm looking for a solution where my bot can understand users request(may be with LUIS this can be achieved) and verifies/validates the user/requirement with master data. If all good, then connect to my native database(Siebel CRM via API) to perform the defined action and log a reference ticket(via API) and finally send an email to user using outlook. Is this achievable using azure service?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [Bot Framework](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk) can do all of those things:

> my bot can understand users request

[LUIS](https://www.luis.ai) is perfect for this.

> verifies/validates the user/requirement with master data

All of this can be done within [Waterfall dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-dialog?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#waterfall-dialogs) or [Prompts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-dialog?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#prompts). You can either store the master data in the bot code, or query it from an external source and have the bot validate against it.

[Here's a good sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/05.multi-turn-prompt) for prompts and validation.

> connect to my native database(Siebel CRM via API) to perform the defined action and log a reference ticket(via API)

The bot runs on C#/Node, so anything (including calling your APIs) that you can do in C#/Node, you can do in your bot.

> send an email to user using outlook

Bot Framework has a specific [Email Channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-email?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) for this or you can use the [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mail-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0).

---

#### Recommended Resources

- [Docs and QuickStarts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)
- [Samples Repo](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-samples)
- Reference Docs: [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) / [TypeScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-core/?view=botbuilder-ts-latest)
- [LUIS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/what-is-luis)

Comment: Thanks, Richardson. I will look into the docs and revert for any clarifications.